# Range of $f(x) =\frac {x -1}{x^2 -2x + 3} $?

Tags: calculus, functions

Is my solution for finding the range of 
$$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2 -2x + 3} $$
correct?
Since its Domain is $ \mathbb{R} $, so transforming this equation into $x$ in terms of $y$ , we get $$ yx^2 - (2y +1)x + (3y+1) = 0 $$
Now, since $ x \in \mathbb {R} $ , so its discriminant $\mathbb{D}$ must be $ \ge 0 $, so we have, $$ (2y + 1)^2 - 4y(3y + 1) \ge 0 $$

Solving it, we get
$$ y \in \left[-{1 \over {2 \sqrt2}}, {1 \over {2 \sqrt2}}\right] $$
Kindly solve my problem.

Comment: Did you mean $y \in \left[-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right]$?

Comment: Yes, Kindly tell me what the correct solution is ?

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks good, except you have a small mistake in your equation. **Edit: There is no mistake anymore after OP edited his question**

It should be $y x^2 - (2y + 1)x + 3y - 1 = 0$. This is solvable if and only if $$(2y + 1)^2 - 4y(3y - 1) = -8y^2 + 8y + 1 \ge 0.$$
The roots of $-8y^2 + 8y + 1 = 0$ are at
$$\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{6}}{4},$$
so we need to have $y \in \left[\frac{2 - \sqrt{6}}{4}, \frac{2 + \sqrt{6}}{4}\right]$.

Comment: I am so sorry for posting wrong question.. Anyway, I have edited the question. Kindly have a look. I would be extremely thankful if you give me the solution.

Comment: @KUNJESH KUMAR MISHRA: Your solution to the edited question looks correct.

Comment: But the answer given is $$ \left[{1 \over {4}}( 1-\sqrt3), {1 \over {4}}( 1+\sqrt3)\right] $$. Due to this I am facing problem. Kindly help me.

Comment: @ J.J That should be $  y\,x^2 - (2y +1)x + (3y+1) = 0 $

Comment: @KUNJESHKUMARMISHRA: Maybe you want to shorten your name, only MISH appears here :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative method:

Write $f(x)$ as $\frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2+2}$. Thus, your function is a horizontal shift of $g(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+2}$, and hence these functions have the same range.

Next, $g$ is odd, so it is sufficient to study positive $t$ (for which $g$ is positive). Now, by the arithmetic-geometric mean $t^2+2\geq 2\sqrt{t^2}\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{2}t$ with equality when $t^2=2$. Thus the maximum value is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. With symmetry, the minimum is $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Thus, the range is (by continuity) $[-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}]$.

Answer (score 1):

We can more easily find out maxima/minima to find its range:

To find where extrema occur by Quotient Rule:

$$ \frac{x-1}{x^2-2 x +3} = \frac{1}{2 x -2 } $$

Solving,
$$ x = 1 \pm \sqrt 2 $$

Extreme values are:

$$ \pm \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{4} $$

which is the range.

[image: RangeOfFunction]

Comment: But the answer given is
$$ \left[ \frac{1}{4}(1−\sqrt3),\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt3) \right] $$
. Due to this I am facing problem. Kindly help me.

Comment: In your post the range and in my above calculation also range is $ \pm \sqrt 2 /4 $. So now you face no problems. Just find out how $ \frac{\pm \sqrt 3 +1}{4} $ is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When the inequality is solved, I get the answer is yϵ[-1/√3,1/√3]

Comment: Your solution is incorrect.